# Need to convert global variables into local variables in C

Tags: c, variables, global-variables, opencl, local

Basically, I sloppily coded an OpenCL program for an assignment using these global variables:

```
int devType = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU;

cl_int err;         /* Error code returned from api calls.  */
size_t global;      /* Global domain size for our calculation.  */
size_t local;           /* Local domain size for our calculation.  */

cl_platform_id cpPlatform;  /* openCL platform.  */
cl_device_id device_id; /* Compute device id.  */
cl_context context;     /* Compute context.  */
cl_command_queue commands;  /* Compute command queue.  */
cl_program program;     /* Compute program.  */
cl_kernel kernel;       /* Compute kernel.  */

/* Create data for the run.  */
float *data = NULL;     /* Original data set given to device.  */
float *results = NULL;  /* Results returned from device.  */
unsigned int correct;       /* Number of correct results returned.  */
cl_mem input;           /* Device memory used for the input array.  */
cl_mem output;      /* Device memory used for the output SUM.  */

int rc = EXIT_FAILURE;
```

Now I'm trying to make them all local in order to tidy the program up.

I converted a global variable N by just moving it away from the variables above into the main() function. I then updated every function header that used N to have 'int N' as a parameter, and passed N into any function calls that needed it as an argument. The program worked as expected.

So I suppose what I'm asking is, for the rest of these variables, will it be that simple? I understand the concepts of passing by reference and value and realise some functions may change variables, so I'll need to use pointer referencing/dereferencing. My concern is that my pointer theory is a little rough and I'm worried I'll run into problems. I also am unsure whether my defined functions can take all of these cl variables.

Also, is there anything wrong with using the same variable names within the functions?

EDIT:

As I feared, a problem does occur in the following functions when trying to localise device_id:

```
void deviceSetup(int devType) {
    cl_platform_id cpPlatform;  /* openCL platform.  */

    /* Connect to a compute device.  */
    if (CL_SUCCESS != clGetPlatformIDs (1, &cpPlatform, NULL))
        die ("Error: Failed to find a platform!");

    /* Get a device of the appropriate type.  */
    if (CL_SUCCESS != clGetDeviceIDs (cpPlatform, devType, 1, &device_id, NULL))
        die ("Error: Failed to create a device group!");
}

/* Create a compute context.  */
void createContext(cl_int err){
    context = clCreateContext (0, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &err);
    if (!context || err != CL_SUCCESS)
        die ("Error: Failed to create a compute context!");
}

/* Create a command commands.  */
void createCommandQueue(cl_int err) {
    commands = clCreateCommandQueue (context, device_id, 0, &err);
    if (!commands || err != CL_SUCCESS)
        die ("Error: Failed to create a command commands!");
}       

void createAndCompile(cl_int err){
    /* Create the compute program from the source buffer.  */
    program = clCreateProgramWithSource (context, 1,
                                         (const char **) &KernelSource,
                                         NULL, &err);
    if (!program || err != CL_SUCCESS)
        die ("Error: Failed to create compute program!");

    /* Build the program executable.  */
    err = clBuildProgram (program, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
    {
        size_t len;
        char buffer[2048];

        clGetProgramBuildInfo (program, device_id, CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG,
                               sizeof (buffer), buffer, &len);
        die ("Error: Failed to build program executable!\n%s", buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you find yourself passing more than say 4 parameters to a function, consider `typedef struct {...} Context` - pass related parameters around in one struct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've answered your own question really. Yes, that really is all there is to it. You may want to consider combining a large number of **related** variables into a struct and pass just a pointer to that struct if you find you've generated massive parameter lists for your functions but that's about it. (There is a tiny degree of performance consideration relating to the number of parameters you pass to any function, but I think for now that's an unnecessary level of complication you could do without!)

There's no getting away from understanding pointers in C though (the only way to pass by reference) so a small project like this might well be an ideal time to strengthen that knowledge!

OK, let's have an example, life's always better explained that way.

We have:

```
int cheddar;
int montereyjack;
int brie;

void print_cheeses(void)
{
    printf("I have %d cheddar %d montereyjack and %d brie\n", cheddar, montereyjack, brie);
}

void add_cheeses(void)
{
   cheddar = cheddar + 1;
   montereyjack = montereyjack + 1;
   brie = brie + 1;
   print_cheeses();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    add_cheeses();
    printf ("Now I have %d cheddars %d jacks %d bries\n", cheddar, montereyjack, brie);
}
```

What we need to get to is:

```
// By value here because we're not changing anything
void print_cheeses(int cheds, int jacks, int bries)
{
    printf("I have %d cheddar %d montereyjack and %d brie\n", cheds, jacks, bries);
}

// Pointers here because we need to change the values in main
void add_cheeses(int *cheese_one, int *cheese_two, int *cheese_three)
{
   *cheese_one = *cheese_one + 1; // We're following the pointer to get to the data we want to change
   *cheese_two = *cheese_two + 1;
   *cheese_three = *cheese_three + 1;
   print_cheeses(*cheese_one, *cheese_two, *cheese_three); // We're following the pointer to get to the data we want to print
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int cheddar = 0;
    int montereyjack = 0;
    int brie = 0;

    add_cheeses(&cheddar, &montereyjack, &brie);

    printf ("Now I have %d cheddars %d jacks %d bries\n", cheddar, montereyjack, brie);
}
```

But it can be a pain passing all three values each time, and since they're related you could bundle them together in one struct and just pass a pointer to that struct about.

Comment: I see. And is keeping all of the variables declared in the main actually localising them? Would it not be even better to declare as many variables as possible in the functions themselves?

Comment: Of course! Only pass them about if you need them. Try and keep them as "local" as you can.

Comment: Okay, as I guessed I am getting some kind of error. On the console, I get "Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.". This occurs when trying to either make the computer device id local to the main or when trying to localise it to four functions that it is called in in the program. Why could this be?

Comment: You're probably mangling a pointer somewhere... Post the code (probably most cleanly as another question) and we can go from there!

Comment: Whoops, posted it above as I felt it related to my original question. Should I make a new question?

Comment: Nope, that's fine. Is that *ALL* of it? I can't see where you're defining device_id at the moment...

Comment: device_id at the moment is simply defined at the top of the program like so: cl_device_id device_id; /* Compute device id.  */

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19547/discussion-between-chucky-and-joe)